# HTML5 footnote coding with "NAME"

Tags: html, anchor

I have hundreds of footnotes in scores of documents.

All are in HTML4 format. I have needed to update all the pages to HTML5.

When using a code checker for HTML5, I am informed that "NAME" as be deprecated and it I am getting warnings in to change the code.

I can't find a code example to resolve this. I am not looking to do anything fancy. I don't want to display the footnote by hovering the mouse over the call to the footnote. I just want to be able to click on a footnote number and get to it at the bottom of the page and then return! I don't see how that is done without "NAME."

Currently as an example, this is what a my code looks like. (I make have ten or more footnotes on any given page.

```
<P>This is in the regular text
<A NAME="sdfootnote1anc" HREF="#sdfootnote1sym"><SUP>1</SUP></A>></P>
```

AND it calls this at the bottom of the page.

```
<p><DIV ID="sdfootnote1">
    <A NAME="sdfootnote1sym" HREF="#sdfootnote1anc">1</A> - Here I am explaining it before I go on after the break to the next footnote.</DIV><BR>
```

Comment: The [warning message from the W3C HTML checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%253C%2521DOCTYPE%2520html%253E%253Ctitle%253ETest%253C%252Ftitle%253E%253CA%2520CLASS%253D%2522sdfootnotesym%2522%2520NAME%253D%2522sdfootnote1sym%2522%2520HREF%253D%2522%2523sdfootnote1anc%2522%253E1%253C%252FA%253E) for this case reports exactly what to do to fix it: *Warning: The `name` attribute is obsolete. Consider putting an `id` attribute on the nearest container instead.*

Comment: @sideshowbarker: What should be done in the case of two anchors that point to each other, as is the case here, where linking to the nearest container of each is not ideal? James's answer seems sound. What do you think?

Comment: @BoltClock Dunno — but maybe the warning message from the checker shouldn’t say anything about “nearest container” but instead just say, “Use the `id` attribute instead”?

Comment: @sideshowbarker: I think the message is mostly fine, because in the vast majority of cases a named anchor isn't pointing anywhere else, so the element should be removed entirely in favor of putting an id on some other element nearby (which may or may not be its container). This is more of an edge case.

Answer (score 2):

Change name to id

```
 <A CLASS="sdfootnoteanc" id="sdfootnote1anc" HREF="#sdfootnote1sym">


 <A CLASS="sdfootnotesym" id="sdfootnote1sym" HREF="#sdfootnote1anc">1</A>
```